# Django ManyToMany relationship not persisting

Tags: python, django

I've encountered a nuisance in a Django application on which I'm working where when a user attempts to create a many-to-many relationship then that relationship does not persist. I can create such relationships via the admin interface, though.

Here's some code which I hope might explain it.

models.py:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    linked_bar = models.ManyToManyField(Bar, blank=True)
    ...
```

views/foo.py:

```
def editFoo(request,foo_id):
    fooQuery = Foo.objects.filter(id=foo_id)
    if len(fooQuery) > 0:
       foo = fooQuery.get(id=foo_id)
    else:
        # handle error &c.
    ...
    print str(len(foo.linked_bar.all())) # prints '0'
    linked_bar_id = request.POST.get('linked-bar-id', '')
    barQuery = Bar.objects.filter(id=linked_bar_id)
    if len(barQuery) > 0:
       bar = barQuery.get(id=bar_id)
       foo.linked_bar.add(bar)
       print str(len(foo.linked_bar.all())) # prints '1'
    return redirect("/foo/" + foo_id) # calls showFoo()

def showFoo(request,foo_id):
    fooQuery = Foo.objects.filter(id=foo_id)
    if len(fooQuery) > 0:
       foo = fooQuery.get(id=foo_id)
    ...
    print str(len(foo.linked_bar.all())) # prints '0'
```

So, the ManyToMany relationship appears to be being created in foo.py during the edit stage, but doesn't persist to where it should be shown to the user. Can anyone suggest what might be happening here, or where I might look for further clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand what is attempting to be done because of the generic names, but I will attempt to rewrite your code using a few recommended conventions, and it should hopefully clear up any errors you are having:

```
def editFoo(request, foo_id):

    try:
        foo_obj = Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)
    except Foo.DoesNotExist:
        ...  # Handle error here

    ...  # More code here?

    print foo_obj.linked_bar.count()  # Prints current linked_bar count

    linked_bar_id = request.POST.get('linked-bar-id', '')

    try:
        bar_obj = Bar.objects.get(id=linked_bar_id)
    except Bar.DoesNotExist:
        ...  # Handle error here

    if bar_obj:
       foo_obj.linked_bar.add(bar_obj)
       print foo_obj.linked_bar.count()  # Prints current linked_bar count
    return redirect("/foo/" + foo_id)  # Calls showFoo()


def showFoo(request, foo_id):
    foo_obj = Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)

    ...  # More code here?
    print foo_obj.linked_bar.count()  # Prints current linked_bar count
    return render(request, 'TEMPLATE.html', {'foo': foo_obj})  # Replace 'TEMPLATE.html' with your template name
```

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting to see the different conventions; I inherited this project coming from a Rails background, and I'm not very familiar with Python. Unfortunately, it's not a matter of convention here; something else seems to be going on.

Comment: I also cleared some errors on top of the restructuring, does it work for you now? If not, then paste the error you are receiving and I will do my best to help.

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors. The code appears to run without issue but after adding to linked_bar then linked_bar.count() shows 0 in showFoo, i.e. the association does not persist. Changing the conventions makes no difference, and I wonder where in the guts of Django I might look to try to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be that there was some other code elsewhere in the application which wiped out foo.linked_bar after I'd added to it, which I did not spot initially. So, a trivial matter in the end, but most annoying.

I'll accept the other answer due to the useful coding convention suggestions.